# Filtering by more than one property by a logical AND operation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 4 checkboxes above a table, which the user can use to filter items from the table.

I'm currently using `Array.prototype.filter` to filter the results, but I'm sure my logic within it is incorrect.

The filters I have now are basically:

```
// Note: a, b, c, and d are booleans representing the checked 
//  state of each checkbox. They essentially map to a property on each 
//  object in the array.
arry.filter(function(i) {
  if(a) return i.hasA;
  if(b) return i.hasB;
  if(c) return i.hasC;
  if(d) return i.hasD;
});
```

The result here is not what I would like. I'd like to do something like:

```
if(a && b && c && d) return i.hasA && i.hasB && i.hasC && i.hasD;
```

But the permutations for that would get way out of hand. There's got to be a simpler way to do this natively.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the checkboxes to be treated as OR (include results that meet any of the checked options) or AND (include results that meet all of the checked options)?

Comment: What do you mean by "persisting previous filters"?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make this more clear. The checkboxes are to be treated as AND operators. Essentially, when all 4 are checked, then the filter should only return items that have all 4 properties set to true.

Comment: I updated the title to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: What is the logic you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: The filters represent 4 different products the company offers. The objects in the array have 4 properties on them, which are booleans on whether or not that object has that product in it. I'm trying to allow users to filter the list, narrowing down objects that have all checked products in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arry.filter(function(i) {
  return (!a || i.hasA) &&
         (!b || i.hasB) &&
         (!c || i.hasC) &&
         (!d || i.hasD);
});
```

Let's just examine the first of four tests.

If "A" is unchecked (i.e. `a` is false), then the test passes.  Alternatively, if "A" is checked (i.e. `a` is true), then we require `i.hasA` to be true for the test to pass.

Similarly, either `b` is unchecked, or `i` must have property B.

… etc.

Comment: This works, but reading over it again, it doesn't seem logically correct? For example... if `a` is checked, then won't the filter return `true` for that `item`? It seems like it will return early, even before checking the property `hasA`? It's working in the app though, so I must be wrong, I just don't understand it.

Comment: Answer has been edited to explain. I now understand. Thank you @200_success